# Gradually fill object (correct design?)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

## General Problem

I have some objects that have some variables that are not known at creation time.

Right now I create these objects and gradually fill them until they are fully instantiated. But I'm wondering, "Is it a good design to gradually fill an object until it is fully instantiated?".

## My Specific Problem

I'm developing a Java program that has a hierarchy of *Task* objects. These tasks have some variables that are known when I create them, and some variables that only become known when the task is being scheduled. Right now I create these tasks with the variables that are known, and when the task is ready for scheduling I call *scheduleTask(Task t)* and this method will set the variables that become known when the task is being scheduled.

But is it a good solution to create objects that are not fully instantiated, and set the remaining variables when they become known?

I was thinking about deferring the task creation until all variables are known (when it is being scheduled). But some taks can only be scheduled after getting an approval from external sources.

Does somebody have some design ideas on how to solve this problem?

*EDIT*: I forgot to mention that I have different types of Tasks that all inherit from "Task".

*EDIT 2*: How about "ProposedTask" objects that have the variables that are known before scheduling? References to these can be hold until it gets approval. Then a new "Task" can be created while scheduling based upon the "ProposedTask" object ('scheduleTask(ProposedTask p)' now takes a ProposedTask object).

Comment: I don't understand how "But some tasks can only be scheduled after getting an approval from external sources" is related to filling the Task.  Your suggestion right before that line that you wait until you have the variables before creating the Task seems to be a clean option.  But I guess there's something wrong which I don't understand...

Comment: @toto2: I want to make a Task beforehand because then I can store a list of references to Tasks that need approval. Once a Tasks gets the approval it needs, it will be scheduled and the rest of its variables will be set while it is being scheduled.

Comment: I guess you should instead only put the tasks in a list when they are ready.  Or you could have two lists: one for all tasks and one for tasks which are ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Builder pattern. E.g:

```
Task.Builder b = new Task.Builder():
b.knownProperty(value).anotherProperty(value2);

myExecutor.schedule(b);


...
void schedule(Task.Builder b) {
    b.propertyBeforeExecute(value);
    Task t = b.build();
}
```

Many frameworks use it to create partially created objects and then execute some action. E.g.: Http requests builders -> HttpPool executors

Comment: I forgot the mention that I have different types of Tasks. "Task" is the superclass where all other Tasks inherit from.

How I see the Builder pattern is that it is useful to create objects with different properties of the same class. Or do I see this the wrong way?

Comment: The Builder pattern solves exactly this ".. gradually fill an object until it is fully instantiated...". Consider an Http request (I don't take your example because I don't know the domain) you can create a HttpRequestBuilder, fill the header, the url, the get parameters, etc. At this point you can build the HttpRequest. But, you can later add more properties and build a new one. So, you can see the Builder as a Template/Factory. I'd recommend to read and try to implement one. There is a eclipse plugin that does the dirty job for you. This is a well known pattern (E.g. StringBuilder)

Comment: Regarding the class hierarchy. Not sure how the complexity or the details of your design. But, you can have several builders (probably with a similar hierarchy) or a single one being in combination with an Abstract Factory (another pattern) that creates the different instances and takes the builder as base template.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if it makes sense to you....

To initialize variables in an object and fill them in later, you could set them to null

```
public class MyClass {
 public int firstvar=null;
 public String secondvar=null;

 public String useVars() {
   if(firstvar!=null && secondvar!=null)return firstvar+" "+secondvar;
   else return null;
 }
}
public class Main {
 MyClass m;
 String result;
 public void runIt(){
  m=new MyClass();
  m.firstvar=5;
  result=m.useVars();
 }

 public void doLater(){
  m.secontvar="hello";
  result=m.useVars();
 }
}
```

To be even more fancy, you could use custom exceptions.....

```
public String useVars throws MyCustomException(){ /* .... */ 
 if(firstvar==null || secondvar==null)throw new MyCustomException("ERROR!!!!!!!");
}


public class MyCustomException extends Exception {
 public CustomException(String s){ super(s);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your class is complex, to simplify the state checking and compartmentalize the invalid state, consider putting all of the TBD fields into a separate class (perhaps just an inner class).  Then set it to null, or have it implement a readyToGo() method, and it's an easier check if they have been filled in or not.  Your Task object will have a stable, valid state.  e.g.  (skipping many getters and setters, they may not be needed anyway, use package access)

```
public class Task {

   final int known1;           // the final is optional but I usually use it
   final String known2;
   final TBD tbd = new TBD();  // might be transient depending on your persistance???

   public Task(int known1, String known2) {
      this.known1 = known1;
      this.known2 = known2;
   }

   public void submit() {
      if (!tbd.readyToRun())
         throw new IllegalStateException();
      // do real work here...
   }

   public void setTBDSomething(int something) { tbd.something = something; }
   public void setTBDStartDate(Date startWhen) { tbd.startWhen = startWhen; }


   class TBD {
      int something;
      Date startWhen;

      boolean readyToRun() { // Dixie Chicks music optional...
         return something > 0 && startWhen != null;
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may provide a checkStatus instance method to Task class, which would return the status of the task object to know whether it's fully instantiated and ready for scheduling.

Any client code can use this method and take the decisions accordingly.

Comment: I forgot to mention: this is how I do it now. I have a check to check if a task can be scheduled. And I have a check to check if a task is successfully scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is a bad practice to generate an object with invalid state. The main disadvantage in this case is that you need to check of an object every time you go to use it. I prefer to initialize the state on constructor and pass all needed arguments in order to make a valid state, and throw and exception in case of any error in constructor, so in this case you will be sure that any time you go to use an object it will be in an valid state and you can use it safely.

If you need to serialize your object and need a empty constructor + setters getters use Memento design pattern and make the serialization by using memento of this object.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that you need further analysis of the business domain/processes that you are modeling. It sounds like you are trying to model a workflow by changing the object's type for each step in the process.

I got that uh-oh feeling when I thought "I create a task of type ProposedTask, and now it's been scheduled. A scheduled ProposedTask" That's confusing. And my brain boggles when I think of all the type casting, creation of new different-typed objects as the *conceptual* task ***changes state***.

What I see are Tasks (in the general sense) that go from "proposed" to "scheduled" or "disapproved", back and forth, etc. The type (of the object) should not be changing, the object's state should.

If this is a good guess on my part then I'd expect to have a single Task type with all the possible variables declared in it. Add a "myState" property. In each state ("Proposed", "Scheduled") particular variables get their values.